# How to Display data from database inside on a tag using php function

Tags: php, html

I have a database with titles and I want to display them inside of a tag.

```
<?php 
require 'mainphp.php';

    if (isset($_GET['val'])) {
        $id=$_GET['val'];

        if ($id==1) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo '<div class="row" >';
            for ($i=1; $i < 20; $i++) { 
                    echo '<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2" >';
                        echo ('<a href="kwdikoi.php?id='.$i.'" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" >'.displayData("kwdikoi",$i, "title").'</a>');
                    echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }elseif ($id==28) {
            # code...
        }elseif ($id==33) {
            # code...
        }
    }elseif (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        displayData('kwdikoi',$id,'essence');
    }

    ?>
```

**mainphp.php**

```
function displayData($table,$line,$column){

//open SQL CONNECTION
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','alex','labels');
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_query($conn,'set character set UTF8');
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

//SELECT the row from our table 
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id ='".$line."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row[$column];
    }
}else{
    echo "There is no ".$column." in our database.".mysqli_error($conn);
}
//."<br>".$row['title']."<br>".$row['smallindex']."<br>".$row['mainindex']."<br>";
// close SQL connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

}

The `displayData()` is a function that echoes the title . The results that I get is the title outside of the button e.g `title[empty button]` , and I want the title inside the button e.g `[title]` .

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it.
// Strings can be passed individually as multiple arguments
echo 'This ', 'string ', 'was ', 'made ', 'with multiple parameters.', chr(10);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

**Using commas and single quotes.**